# Mahout's datamodel with GenericDataModel

Tags: datamodel, mahout, recommendation-engine

I am playing around with Mahout's recommendation engines and are running into problem with using genericdatamodel object.  My question is if I want to add some new users data into the existing datamodel, is the only way to do it, by reconstruction of a new datamodel by reading all the data again.

Currently, our data is in the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. It's effectively read-only for performance. The general idea is that you don't incorporate data model updates frequently, as it generally means rebuilding a lot of other pre-computed or cached computations.

You could hack it to expose an update method without too much trouble. Just be careful of thread-safety issues.

Comment: Sean, thank you for answering the question. I am quite new to the Mahout framework. When you mentioned about the hacking a update method.  Do you mean hack the datamodel in the library or my own update to push the new data set.  I guess is refresh() call on the datamodel is not for adding the new data set.

Comment: I mean modify the `GenericDataModel` code itself. Yes, the idea is generally to use `refresh()`.